# Leaflet Areaselect remove on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, leaflet

Hi I'm using leaflet areaselect and when I use the remove function on internet explorer I got the following error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'
>
> File: leaflet-areaselect.js, Line: 45, Column: 9

Did anyone of you are enable to run this function on internet explorer ? I tried on chrome and firefox and it was fine.

```
var areaSelect = L.areaSelect({
    width:100, 
    height:150, 
    keepAspectRatio:true
}).addTo(map);

areaSelect.remove();
```

Here's a testcase on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Snj1cB?p=preview

Comment: Added a testcase and error message for you and can say it's reproducable for me on Internet Explorer version 11.0.9600.17501 update 11.0.15

Comment: Hi , I tried on IE 11 and it works but not on IE 10 unfortunatly.

Comment: Very weird, for me it doesn't. But then again there's also inconsistency with Firefox, in the Github issue i posted below my answer someone says he's having the issue with Firefox, but he/she has Ubuntu. I'm having no issues with Firefox. Must be a revision/update thing

Comment: Perhaps because even the addarea function on your testcase is not working on IE 10 but my addarea function is working on IE 10, it's very weird !

Comment: Haven't got access to IE10, so can't verify but i slammed that case together in a second, could be something with the onclick handler. IE what can i say ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some debugging/digging and this is bug. The container element in question gets created here: https://github.com/heyman/leaflet-areaselect/blob/master/src/leaflet-areaselect.js#L52 It's created by using `L.DomUtil.create` which is nothing more than a wrapper for `createElement`: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/dom/DomUtil.js#L22 and applies a classname.

Created elements in Chrome/Safari (webkit) and Firefox have a native `remove()` method, this is not according to the standard. IE does not, hence the error. By my guess  `remove` is nothing more than a wrapper for doing `element.parentNode.removeChild(element);` The creator of the plugin should have used that to keep it crossbrowser compatible.

<s>I recommend filing a bugreport: https://github.com/heyman/leaflet-areaselect/issues</s>

EDIT: There is already an issue filed but not much action/followup, posted a comment and linked to this question: https://github.com/heyman/leaflet-areaselect/issues/10 so he can also reproduce this.

Comment: Thanks It was very usefull , I changed    "this._container.remove()" by "this._container.parentNode.removeChild(this._container)" and it works great on every browser . The function remove still works on IE 11 by the way .

Comment: As explained in the comment under your question, for me it doesn't, but it doesn't matter anymore because the issue is already solved: https://github.com/heyman/leaflet-areaselect/issues/10#issuecomment-73999141